# Receiving iOS production push notifications in background only

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-push-notifications, react-native-push-notification

**My environment:**

```
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-native-push-notification": "7.3.1",
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
```

in xCode turned on `remote notifications` in `Background Modes` and enabled `Push Notifications Service`

iOS `.entitlements` configuration is automatically set to production when the app is built with Xcode and deployed

Utilizing Naver Cloud Platform’s [Simple & Easy Notification Service](https://www.ncloud.com/product/applicationService/sens)

**What I've tried:**

I have created two APNs certificates both with `Apple Push Notification Service SSL (Sandbox & Production)`.

The one of them which is used for sandbox environment is successfully receiving foreground/background notifications.

But while using my production certificate, I'm only receiving push notifications while in background.
I did actually resolve this issue by deleting and re-uploading production certificate in the Naver Cloud Platform settings and the iOS app started receiving push notifications in production in the foreground mode.
Then at some moment, push notifications stopped coming in foreground mode again but only background.

Tried debugging, during that period I built and published the ios app several times but didn’t change any cloud platform configuration as well as the source code.

Tried revoking existing production certificates, re-uploading certificates to the cloud service but it didn't work.

My deductive reasoning is that if the Naver Cloud Platform settings along with the server environment and Objective-C code to handle foreground push notifications are all correct since I’m receiving notifications at least in dev environment: foreground/background and at least in production background mode only.

Is there something else I might have missed or should be checking?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the payload which is being sent to APNs in both cases, can you share the payload? 

Also sometimes the APNs backend can be wonky -- after installing the app try rebooting the phone (forget the source on this, but it was some apple.developer.com post)

Comment: There were issues on the server-side with NCP push notifications service. Apart from storing user info (device info and push tokens) in our DB, we had to store it in NCP as well. It appeared that occasionally, for some reasons, NCP wouldn't store user info. Eventually, we decided to replace NCP for FCM and it solved the problem.